# How to draw a pic in asymptote 3d?

Tags: 3d, asymptote

I want to make 3D in Asymptote.

My code:

```
> import three;
import graph3;
//import solids;
currentprojection=orthographic(8,4,2,center=true);

size(10cm);
size3(3cm,5cm,8cm);

draw(unitbox,dashed);

dot(unitbox,red);
xaxis3(Label("$x$",1),xmax=1.25,Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",1),ymax=1.25,Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",1),zmax=1.25,Arrow3);
xaxis3(Label("$\hat{x}$",.5),xmax=.5,Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$\hat{y}$",.5),ymax=.5,Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$\hat{z}$",.5),zmax=.5,Arrow3);
label("$O$",(0,0,0),NW);
draw ((0,0,0) --(1,1,1),Arrow3);
```

[image]

Please help me! Thank U :)

Comment: Welcome! You already have an asymptote code. What is it precisely that you are struggling with, and what you want to have help for?

Comment: I don't know how to customize drawing angles from axes to vector r. please help me. Thank u :)

Comment: Thank minhthien_2016 so much, edit code :)

Answer (score 9):

This is done with much help from [this tutorial](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) and uses `asypictureB` by the same author. You obtain the result e.g. with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\standaloneenv{asypicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=disc}
settings.outformat = "pdf";
settings.prc = false;
settings.render = 0;
import three;
import graph3;
//import solids;
currentprojection=orthographic(8,4,2,center=true);

size(10cm);
size3(3cm,5cm,8cm);

draw(unitbox,dashed);

dot(unitbox,red);
xaxis3(Label("$x$",1),xmax=1.25,Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$",1),ymax=1.25,Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$",1),zmax=1.25,Arrow3);
xaxis3(Label("$\hat{x}$",.5),xmax=.5,Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$\hat{y}$",.5),ymax=.5,Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$\hat{z}$",.5),zmax=.5,Arrow3);
label("$O$",(0,0,0),NW);
draw ((0,0,0) --(1,1,1),Arrow3);
draw(arc(c=O,0.5*X,X+Y+Z), L = Label("$\alpha$", position=MidPoint,align=(0,1)));
draw(arc(c=O,0.5*Y,X+Y+Z), L = Label("$\beta$", position=MidPoint,align=(0,1)));
draw(arc(c=O,0.5*Z,X+Y+Z), L = Label("$\gamma$", position=MidPoint,align=(0,1)));
\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank  Schrödinger's cat so much :)